The pKa of 3,4-dihydroxycyclobutane-1,2-dione (not squaric acid)
Would like to know if 3,4-dihydroxycyclobutane-1,2-dione reacts with NaHCO3 to give effervescence?


Huh, its enol is a vinylogous carboxylic acid, so... maybe.

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/32832/condition-for-nahco3-to-react-to-form-co2-with-organic-acids

p in pH and pKa is always written with a small p.

This question is similar to: What should be the pKa and IUPAC name of this compound?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Mithoron describes that the molecule tautomerizes to a vinylogous carbocylic acid. Here we take a closer look, using the image below (by the post author).

In the top line the tautomerizatiin is shown, in which one of the $\ce{C – H}$ protons is transferred to a conjugated carbonyl oxygen to make the enol (or, ene-1,2-diol) form. When this form is deprotonated at the hydroxyl group indicated in the bottom line, an anion with delocalized bonding and charge is created. Note that although there are four pi electrons, an antiaromatic ring is not formed because the conjugation is not cyclic; the lower left carbon in the diagrams remains saturated.
This anion has its negative charge delocalized between two oxygen atoms and thus the molecule may be expected to have acid strength similar to a carboxylic acid. Accordingly we can expect it to displace carbon dioxide from sodium bicarbonate.
